# Save Paths, Virtual directories, and static locations

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a file upload that was uploading to a folder in the web application root, i.e. I had

```
string savePath = @"~/documentation/"

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePath) + filename);
```

and that worked fine, uploading the file to WebApp/documentation/filename.abc

The problem is, I want to change the documentation location so I don't have to move that folder when pushing from development to production. So I did the following

In Web.Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DocumentationLocation" value="C:\Documentation\" />
</appSettings>
```

In the code:

```
string savePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DocumentationLocation"];

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePath) + filename);
```

I figured this would work identically, saving the file to the folder specified in the web.config.

However, I get an error when I try to upload a document now, that says:

> 'C:\TM_Documentation\' is not a valid virtual path.

any idea what i'm doing wrong so that i can fix it and save the files outside of the web app directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Server.MapPath()`, you don't need the server to map the path for you, because you are giving a full path already.

Comment: perfect. thank you. i'll mark it as answered once the system lets me. (funny how i spent time two days ago researching the mappath thing and working with it only to find out now it's unnecessary. guess that's how it always works.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Server.MapPath` if you have your path as "C:\Documentation\".
`Server.MapPath` is required only if you config has a relative path such as  "~/Documentation/"

Try this

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(savePath + filename);
```